# App to change equalizer based on time

Tags: applications, automation, equalizer

Looking for an app (or other solution) to change equalizer settings based on time of day.

Specifically, I'd like to automatically lower bass (and possibly enhance voice) at nighttime so I don't disturb the neighbors.

Comment: Maybe a job for [tag:tasker] if you can find an equalizer app that can change settings via an intent.